# BTC Hash-Rate API

Tags: api, hash, hashpower

I'd like to get hash-rate of BTC from OKcoin' API(GET /api/v1/charts/:type)

[here](https://www.bihang.com/about/block_api.html) is OKCoin's API web site.

How can I get information from  [here](https://www.bihang.com/about/block_api.html) is OKCoin's API web site.

`python
gets = requests.get("http://block.okcoin.cn/api/v1/charts/hash-rate.do")
gets.json()`

OUT
{'error_code': 10010, 'result': False}

Comment: Your links seem to lead to another website than OKCoin's website. Is that intended?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a Hash-Rate endpoint in OKCoin's API anymore, but I found an endpoint from [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate)

To get the data programmatically, you can call:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate")
print(response.json())
```